# Populate the default values of an input tag from a list of objects in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a list of objects from which I would like populate the input tag in a form.

For example, suppose I have a list `x = [{id:1, email:"one@xyz.com"},{id:2,"two@xyz.com"}]`.

Here x is a List and the `{}` represents an object (consider instances of a generic student class).

What I want is:
to have a input field in thymeleaf pre-populated with the emails of each object from the list x.

So the input field would have the default value of `one@xyz.com, two@xyz.com`

What I have tried:

`<input th:field="${x}"/>` populated the input field with just the ids but I wanted them to be populated with email.
As of now input field will have default value of `1,2`

The actual code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="modulePOCinput">POC </label>
                
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modulePOCinput"
                        th:field="*{notificationList}" />
                
            </div>
```

notification list is the list that contains several ModuleNotificationDetails objects shown below
note: notification list is an attribute of a greater object that I have not shown here.

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ModuleNotificationDetails 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "modulePoc_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="modulePoc_id_generator", sequenceName = "NOTIFICATION_DETAILS_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;
    
    @NonNull
    private String email;
    
    
}
```

Could you please help me solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely not a problem to call methods in Thymeleaf - so as long as ${obj} represents an Object of the ModuleNotificationDetails class you can call method getEmail on it like so ${obj.getEmail()} or a shorter version that Thymeleaf recognizes is ${obj.email}

you can also iterate in Thymeleaf, so since x is the list:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="item: ${x}"> <input th:field="${item.email}"/> </li>
</ul>
```